# Why does Belle mean in this part in "A Change in Me"

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, beauty-and-the-beast-musical, alan-menken

In the musical Beauty and the Beast (composed by the legend Alan Menken himself), Belle sings the song "A Change in Me" after she returns to her father when the Beast lets her go. She tells (or rather sings) to her father,

> And I - I never thought I'd leave behind
>   My childhood dreams
>   But I don't mind
>   For now I love the world I see
>   No change of heart
>   A change in me
>
> For in my dark despair
>   I slowly understood
>   My perfect world out there
>   Had disappeared for good
>
> But in its place I feel
>   A truer life begin
>   And it's so good and real
>   It must come from within

What does Belle mean in this passage? What childhood dream did she love behind? What did she not love about the world she saw before? What's the perfect world that disappeared? What truer life? What does she mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the early Act I song “[Belle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyq5VI2486I#t=5m10s)” she complained about the monotony of small-town life:

> Little town, it’s a quiet village
>   Every day like the one before […]
>   Every morning just the same
>   Since the morning that we came
>   To this poor provincial town […]
>   There must be more than this provincial life!

and in “[Belle (reprise)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyq5VI2486I#t=30m40s)” she described her dreams:

> I want much more than this provincial life!
>   I want adventure in the great wide somewhere
>   I want it more than I can tell
>   And for once it might be grand
>   To have someone understand
>   I want so much more than they’ve got planned

So these are her “childhood dreams”—to escape from the provinces, have adventures, travel places, and have people understand her ambitions.

But by “[A Change in Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyq5VI2486I#t=1h55m55s)” (late in Act II), she realises that if she marries the Beast she is going to have to stay in the provinces, and will never have the “perfect world” she imagined for herself in Paris or wherever. But she is happy with this because she loves him, and so feels that this will be the “truer life”.